# Why would you ever not assign your full crew on a job?

Tags: firefly

Just got the firefly boardgame a few weeks ago and have a couple group games and two solo plays done.
One thing I can't figure out yet is why you wouldn't always assign your entire crew to a job.
No matter if they are assigned they are need to be payed and will get disgruntled if you do an immoral job and they are moral, so the only reason I can see is if you are ready doing a Niska job and don't want to risk them getting killed.

I am still playing the stock game, no expansions yet.  Really looking forward to snagging pirates and bounty hunters, the added player interaction seems to be the one glaring hole in the mechanics so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question makes no sense; the game has no concept of assigning crew to a job.

That said, it is possible that some crew members are not available to Misbehave. For example, Shepherd Book stays on the ship for immoral jobs, River Tam may have returned to the ship due to an earlier roll, and a medic may have returned a crew to the ship to heal.

[image: Shepherd Book]

Comment: What rule are you referring to here?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand, do you think you could include this rule in your answer? I'm only seeing implicit references.

Comment: @freekvd  I edited the answer to include an example card (assuming it gets accepted by the review).  I only found two cards in the base game that affect this rule.  Hopefully its flushed out a bit more in expansions.

Comment: I am confused as well; I don't know what rule the you are referring to. Your answer mentions "this rule", but the question doesn't ask about any rule.

Comment: That sounds much more like a lack of a rule than a rule. The OP doesn't make mention of the fact that there's a rule saying you don't have to assign everyone to a job. He just asks why you wouldn't choose to assign everyone to a job.

Comment: My point is you don't need a rule to say that you can choose not to assign everyone. Unless there's a rule saying "you must assign all crew members", then you would be able to assign just the ones you want. Either way, it's not a big deal at all; but I wasn't the only one confused by the answer.

Comment: @GendoIkari, hum, turns out there is no such rule. The OP made it all up, and I was simply remembered the possibility of crew being on the ship. Updated the answer.

Comment: The way I read the question, it's more like the OP thinks the best strategy is to always put all crew members on each mission, and he is wondering why not to do this (other than when someone can't go, or could die).

Comment: @freekvd, You can't "not do this". There's no concept of putting crew on a mission. Anyway, if you think I answered the wrong question, why don't you answer you think is the actual question?

Comment: No I think you got it just right with your last edit.

Comment: I think the misunderstanding is probably due to the fact that you _assign Equipment_. Step 1 of working a job is "Equip Crew" (page 13 of official rules): "You must commit to what Gear you’re carrying while Working the Job. Each Crew and Leader may only carry 1 Gear card." That's probably what the op confused as assigning crew (not a rule) instead of assign equipment to crew (a rule and first step of working a job).